# BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(String method, String uri)

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

Can someone help me in getting more information about
`BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(String method, String uri)`.

[This](http://hc.apache.org/) did not help me understand the said topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do with BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest?  An entity in httpcomponents refers to the body or the payload of the request.

You should be using sub classes of HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase that is HttpPut, HttpPost or HttpPatch when sending a HTTP request that has a body.
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html

You should read the [HttpClient Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/), particularly chapter 1 to get you started.